# How to make http requests from api hosted on heroku

Tags: angular, spring-boot, heroku

I'm developing two modules, one API(hosted in **heroku**) and one module **Angular 5(LocalHost).**

I'm trying to access some endpoints from my **API(Spring Boot)** and it's returning me the following error:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/empresa from localhost:4200 to https://jdjone-ws.herokuapp.com (undefined) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

But when I test the same end point in **PostMan**, it returns me the correct values:

[image: Values from my API]

could someone give me an example of how to configure ?. I'm grateful!!!!

**My proxy.config.json:**

```
    {
   "/api/*": {
     "target": "https://jdjone-ws.herokuapp.com",
     "seguro": false
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured CORS for SpringBoot API? See https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: In this case covered by Spring, should I activate CORS in my api for my LocalHost ??

Comment: Yes. In case fronted is running as a separate process, we should enable CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved, just use the method:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        }
    };
}
```

Thank you very much, K. Siva Prasad Reddy!!!!!!!!